# How to add div blocks after certain set of post

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, query

Ok I broke my post down into different style settings. Like shown below. The first post is a large block. the next four post are small and aligned next to the larger post.

[image]

I used the loop below to achieve this affect.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<!--First Post -->
<?php elseif ($count <= 1) : ?>
<div class="style-1"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<!--Next Four Boxes -->
<?php elseif ($count <= 5) : ?>
<div class="style-2"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<!--Next Six Boxes -->
<?php elseif ($count <= 10) : ?>
<div class="style-3"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, my question is. **How do I break the loop to add a special div after the first five post and continue the loop after the special div?** Like photo'd below. The gray area. I'm also going to want to add another special div after the next six post, each special div will have different content.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use % to set the template(style) or you can use :nth-child(16n+1) ...

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php $st = 16; //after how many blocks you want to repeat the pattern 
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count%$st == 1) : ?>
<div class="style-1"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php elseif ($count%$st == 2 || $count%$st == 3) : ?>
<div class="style-2"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php elseif ($count%$st == 4 || $count%$st == 5 || $count%$st == 6) : ?>
<div class="style-3"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php elseif ($count%$st == 7 || $count%$st == 8 || $count%$st == 9 || $count%$st == 10) : ?>
<div class="style-4"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php elseif ($count%$st == 11 || $count%$st == 12 || $count%$st == 13 || $count%$st == 14 || $count%$st == 15 ) : ?>
<div class="style-5"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php elseif ($count%$st == 0 ) : ?>
<div class="style-6"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

or (I'm not sure if I understand what you need)

```
<?php if($count % $st == 0){?>
// do your code
<?php }?> 
//continue with your loop code
```

Try this code

```
    <?php if (have_posts()) :
    $count = 0;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $count++;
        if ($count  == 1) : ?> <!--first box -->
            <div class="style-1"><?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php elseif ($count  > 1 && $count  <5) : ?></div> <!--next three boxes -->
            <div class="style-2"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php elseif ($count  == 5) : ?> <!-- box five and break div -->
            <div class="style-2"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="first-break-div"><?php /* the content from first break div */ ?></div>
        <?php elseif ($count >5 && $count < 11) : ?> <!--next five boxes -->
            <div class="style-3"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php elseif ($count == 12) : ?> <!--last box and last break div -->
            <div class="style-3"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
            <div class="last-break-div"><?php /* the content from last break div */ ?></div>
        <?php endif;
    endwhile;
endif; ?>
```

This was my output

```
<div class="style-1"></div>
<div class="style-2"></div>
<div class="style-2"></div>
<div class="style-2"></div>
<div class="style-2"></div>
<div class="first-break-div"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="style-3"></div>
<div class="last-break-div"></div>
```

Comment: let say you want after 6 posts to add a new `<div>`, you will use `if($count % 6 == 0){ /*add my div*/ }`

Comment: something like this
`<?php
// I want a new div after 6 post
$st = 6;
$count = 0;
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $count++;
    //do the loop
    if($count%6==0){
?>
    <div class="break-div"></div>
<?php
    }
endwhile;
?>`

Comment: I'm not following what is this line that was added `<?php $st = 16; //after how many blocks you want to repeat the pattern`

Comment: after 16 posts, the style will repeat, if you have like 30 posts, won't check for 30 posts to see what style you'll use

Comment: Is the the the simplest way. You gave me many options and now i'm confused. Each break div will have different content.

Comment: how you will set that content? and how many break div you'll have? 
Maybe I can help you with the code

Comment: I will have only two break divs. I'm trying to achieve this---> http://oi58.tinypic.com/30kx350.jpg and the music section I want to add another section like that under the next 6 set of post. But it won't be music. I would love if you can help me with this.

Comment: Discover hot music it's a break div and after last white box will be another break div right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.....Also i made an edit to my post. The code. @Alex

Comment: Check my last section from my first answer.

Comment: I don't understand why you did the codes like this `<?php elseif ($count  == 2 || $count  == 3) : ?>` the code i have `<?php elseif ($count <= 5) : ?>` displays the next 4 post and I want to break after those 4. Also I tried that and it didn't work. It only added the div break after each post.

Comment: check again the answer, I make it better and faster.

Comment: Andries that didn't work either ....

Comment: Got it. This line `<?php elseif ($count  > 1 && $count  <5) : ?>` was inside the `</div>` break above it.